# Return even numbers using *args

Tags: python, args

I want to write a function that returns even numbers in a list fromatby using *args to take in a undefined number of values and just returning the values that are even

```
def myfunc(*args):
  if args%2==0:
      return args
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try list comprehension:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [a for a in args if a % 2 == 0]
```

This gives:

```
>>> myfunc(1,5,4,6,8,7)
[4, 6, 8]
```